# Is there some equation to find the number of paths from the number of junctions?

Tags: python, math

Suppose I have the following possible paths of maze.

[image]

I found the possible paths implementing dead end removal process with image processing.

I wanted to know if there is any equation to find the number of possible paths from the number of available junctions? I am thinking of implementing it in python.

Any other method / algorithm for finding **number** of possible paths can be suggested.

It'll be great if you could be as specific as possible.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: you need to parse image or what?

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement a graph search.

Comment: As soon as there is a loop, there are infinitely many paths. Please clarify what you want and what input you have.

Comment: Can it be done via logic programming using prolog? Please suggest.